# Variations only are generated under certain circumstances but not always

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to generate all the possible variations depending in how many inputs element I have. This is part of the HTML code I have generated:

```
<section id="choices_picker">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="color" id="color_choice5" value="5"> Color</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="talla" id="talla_choice6" value="6"> Size</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="talla" id="talla_choice13" value="13"> Size</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="color_choice_5" style="">
        <span>Color<input type="text" name="input_color[]" class="field_color" data-id="color_5" placeholder="Color"><br></span><button type="button" class="button color">Add color</button>
    </div>
    <div id="talla_choice_6" style="">
        <span>Size<input type="text" name="input_talla[]" class="field_talla" data-id="talla_6" placeholder="Size"><br></span><button type="button" class="button talla">Add size</button>
    </div>
    <div id="talla_choice_13" style="display: none">
        <button type="button" class="button talla">Add size</button>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="button create-variation" id="create-variation" style="">Create variation</button>
    <section id="variations_holder" style=""></section>
</section>
```

This code is dynamically so each time I click on "Add" button a new element is created on the fly, right now I only created some just for testing purposes. If you play with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ggcwz/) I made then you can see what I mean with "code works under certain circumstances but not always" and I can't find where the mistake is so I ask here for some help from people with best knowledge than me. Basically any time you click "Create variation" button a new set with UPC, Price and Quantity should be created even is just only one variation exists. What is a variation? For example has two colors, or has two sizes or has two color and sizes and so on. Any advice on this, please?

Here is a image showing the process at my computer

[image]

PS: Any improvement on code is welcome, I'm still learning jQuery

Comment: what should your code do and waht do you mean with "fails"?

Comment: @TobiasZander I edited the code and title trying to be more explicit as I can, any help is welcome

Comment: It's very hard to make sense of the question. What's UPC, Price and Quantity? There are no such input fields in the fiddle. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JeevanJose they are not in the HTML because isn't generated, if you check some of the checkbox showed there and add values to the input that are created on the fly you can click then "Create variation" and see then the fields you mention before also if you take a look at jQuery code you'll see them there since are created on the fly

Comment: Sorry dude. Would help if I could understand the question.